# Copy and paste x times based on a variable

Tags: vba, count, copy

I have a list of tournament competitors. If the list of competitors exceeds 12 then I need to split the list as equally as possible over 2 tournament rings (ie, if 13 then 7 in 'Ring 1' and 6 in 'Ring 2'). The varibles that dictate how the competitors are split are contained in cell D35 & D37. So I need a piece of code that looks at the value in cell D35 and then carries out a copy a paste sequence (to populate the Ring 1 range) THAT many times. It then needs to do the same for the value shown in D37. Can anyone help with this. I've had a look around on here and the NET and I'm still struggling.

Also, how do I post a sample of my workbook to show what I'm trying to do with the above question??

Kind Regards
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Just split your task in some simple tasks:

-Check if more than 12 competitors

-if more than 12, divide in 2 rings; if not only use 1 ring

-copy the competitors, paste them in the specified ring

(i did not really understand what you meant with your variables ind D35 and D37, however i am not yet allowed to make comments to your post. I will alter this answer if you comment)

I am assuming your list of competitors starts in Cell A1

```
Sub process()
Dim countCompetitors As Integer
Dim amountRing1 As Integer
Dim amountRing2 As Integer

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

countCompetitors = 1

'count the amount of competitors
While Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(countCompetitors, 1))
    countCompetitors = countCompetitors + 1
Wend

countCompetitors = countCompetitors - 1

If countCompetitors Mod 2 = 0 Then
    'amount of competitors is even
    amountRing1 = countCompetitors / 2
    amountRing2 = countCompetitors / 2
Else
    'amount of competitors is odd
    amountRing1 = countCompetitors / 2
    amountRing2 = countCompetitors / 2 - 1
End If

'rng1 and rng2 now contain the competitors
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(amountRing1, 1))
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(amountRing1 + 1, 1), Cells(amountRing1 + amountRing2, 1))

'copy ring1 in column B and ring2 in column C
rng1.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
rng2.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("C2")

End Sub
```

I hope i could help you a bit with that, as already mentioned, please explain what you mean with the variables in Cells D35 and D37, I will alter my code accordingly ;)